# how do i install centos 7 in virtualbox on a windows 10 host without error

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, centos7

I have a new laptop running windows 10. I installed oracle virtual box, then created a virtual drive and tried installing centos 7 on virtual drive, after installation is completed i got the following error upon reboot:

> The instruction at 0x00000000535AC145 referenced memory at 0x0000000003F35A78.  The memory could not be read.
>   Press ok to terminate the program.

Of course after I hit `ok` the program terminates. Then I have to run the install again and I get the same error.  Very aggravating!

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download all your installers again. Preferably from the actual Virtualbox and Centos websites. Maybe the files got corrupted or not completely downloaded. 
Also, you could try to check the logs?

From here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html

> For problem determination, it is often important to collect debugging
>   information which can be analyzed by VirtualBox support. This section
>   contains information about what kind of information can be obtained.
>
> Every time VirtualBox starts up a VM, a so-called "release log file"
>   is created containing lots of information about the VM configuration
>   and runtime events. The log file is called VBox.log and resides in the
>   VM log file folder. Typically this will be a directory like this:
>
> $HOME/VirtualBox VMs/{machinename}/Logs